# How to pass javascript variable to a JSP method?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a javascript codde which a=has a value in its variable which I need to pass to my JSP function but it is not allowing me to pass it on.

Here are my code snippets:

Javascript:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
                var a=$('#frmt').jstree("get_selected");
                    show(a); 
                });
```

Jsp:

```
<%!
public void show(String s){
    out.println("Hello World:"+s);
}
%>
```

Comment: also what will be the import for out.println()

Comment: so when you click the button you want to run show method?

Comment: yes, on click of bbutton javascript method gets called which enables jstree click function and fetches the name of node which I need to pass to my JSP Function

Comment: i don't get it.but if are trying to call a server code from client side you can use ajax.

Comment: can you give snippet which demonstrate it

Comment: You are failing to understand the absolute basics.  Your JSP is translated to HTML on the server. Javascript executes on the client knows nothing about the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression tag instead of `out.println()`. We have tag like

```
<%= "code to print, don't put semicolon after double quote." %>
```

It works as `out.println()` and you can always use `\n` to go to new line of u want.